# CSS Compatibility for Mobile Browsers

Tags: css, mobile

I am trying to find a CSS Compatibility overview for mobile browsers. I am primarily interested in regular CSS2 support. CSS3 support would be great, but my initial concern is about regular positioning, spacing, and other layout properties from CSS2. Does anybody know of an up-to-date compatibility table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite a good one. It may not be entirely up to date but is definitely a start:

http://www.quirksmode.org/m/css.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: It indeed lacks the latest info, but I guess it is the best reference at this point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try http://www.caniuse.com . Compatibility tables for support of HTML5, CSS3, SVG and more in desktop and mobile browsers